# R: Difference between the subsequent ranks of a item group by date

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to derive a ranking of ID given the number of records under a grouped date and find the difference between the sequential ranking of the same ID.

I have managed to derive the ranking

```
data_new <- data_new %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(my_ranks = order(order(Date, NumRecords, decreasing=FALSE)))
```

Results

```
Date  NumRecords ID my_ranks    
2019-03 3   L99887  59     
2019-04 1   L99887  25      
2019-05 1   L99887  22      
2019-06 2   L99887  46  
2019-02 6   L98849  52  
2019-04 19  L98849  108 
2019-05 18  L98849  126 
2019-06 18  L98849  116 
2019-07 17  L98849  136 
2019-08 3   L98849  30
```

Not sure how to add another column representing the difference of the ID ranking with Date.

```
Date  NumRecords ID my_ranks  rank_diff   
2019-03 3   L99887  59          0
2019-04 1   L99887  25          34   
2019-05 1   L99887  22          3
2019-06 2   L99887  46         -24
2019-02 6   L98849  52          0
2019-04 19  L98849  108        -56  
2019-05 18  L98849  126        -18
2019-06 18  L98849  116        10
2019-07 17  L98849  136         -26
2019-08 3   L98849  30          106
```

Comment: you have a typo `116 - 136 = -20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to do a group by 'ID' and then use the `diff`

```
library(dplyr)
data_new %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(Rank_diff = -1 *c(0, diff(my_ranks))) 
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
#   Date    NumRecords ID     my_ranks Rank_diff
#   <chr>        <int> <chr>     <int>     <dbl>
# 1 2019-03          3 L99887       59         0
# 2 2019-04          1 L99887       25        34
# 3 2019-05          1 L99887       22         3
# 4 2019-06          2 L99887       46       -24
# 5 2019-02          6 L98849       52         0
# 6 2019-04         19 L98849      108       -56
# 7 2019-05         18 L98849      126       -18
# 8 2019-06         18 L98849      116        10
# 9 2019-07         17 L98849      136       -20
#10 2019-08          3 L98849       30       106
```

#### data

```
data_new <- structure(list(Date = c("2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06", 
"2019-02", "2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08"
), NumRecords = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 3L), 
    ID = c("L99887", "L99887", "L99887", "L99887", "L98849", 
    "L98849", "L98849", "L98849", "L98849", "L98849"), my_ranks = c(59L, 
    25L, 22L, 46L, 52L, 108L, 126L, 116L, 136L, 30L)),
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: didn't quite get  the ranking difference: the ranking obtained from your code is -34, 83, 104, 70

Comment: Please can you check if it works for the new updated data frame posted in the question

Comment: @Lisa You just need the `group_by`, Updated the post

Comment: Another quick question, as you can see from the example, an ID might have missing value at some date, is it possible to add the missing date with the NumRecord as NA? (i.e. L98849      2019-03 is missing) thanks

Comment: @Lisa Do you have another dataset or vector with all the `IDs` available.  In that case, do a join with that ddataset. ie. `keydat <- data.frame(ID = c("L99887", "L99888", ...); left_join(keydat, out)`

Comment: @Lisa Or if you meant for the 'Date', then `library(tidyr);data_new %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(Rank_diff = -1 *c(0, diff(my_ranks))) %>% complete(Date = unique(.$Date))`